# Admin On Rest "Element Not Found" when doing an Edit View, no error in console

Tags: admin-on-rest

I am trying to open an edit view on an object retrieved from a REST call from a list view. So for example I am retrieving a single user at the url
http://localhost:3000/#/admin/user/5978cf585a65b51ab5463252
And it display all the credentials in the form for a split second and it should(and as in the examples). And then it takes me back to the list view and says "Element not found". Is there a reason for this? I have created my own rest client to deal with my API as well so I don't see why there should be a compatibility thing?
Edit: 
I found a workaround where if I change the rest endpoint to return some random garbage, the data correctly displays and is updated appropriately but this feels hacky, so I assume this is some sort of error?
Edit2:

```js
{
  "_id": "59b6e30fb55e9d7bdfbdc477",
  "__v": 0,
  "created_at": "2017-09-11T19:25:03.169Z",
  "email": "test@gmail.com",
  "info": {
    "first": "Thomas",
    "last": "Test",
    "phone": "778-893-8835"
  },
  "login_type": "facebook",
  "updated_at": "2017-09-11T19:25:03.169Z",
  "verified": false
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your API is returning the element correctly? AOR will optimistically render the page from state usually and might show an error when the actual server response shows up.

Comment: @kunalpareek yes I'm sure, unless there is something missing that I need to add to my header? I have attached what gets sent back(this shows up in the javascript developer console). I have changed my rest client to use _id as the id, so I don't think its that?

Comment: Will need to see more code in that case. You can share your edit view here?

Comment: Are you transforming the result of your API in your restClient so that the resource have an `id` property (and not `_id`) ?